# Thrust: Accessing a device variable created with cudaMallocPitch

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

I have a matrix of data on which I should do some elaboration using the GPU (and thrust library where possible). Up to now, I was able to copy the data to the GPU and writing my own kernel function. Now, based on the output of my kernel function I would exploit the thrust library for other elaboration on the same matrix of data, avoiding if possible to download and re-upload the data from GPU<->CPU.

So, I created a device variable in the GPU using the cudaMallocPitch function:

```
float *d_M;
size_t pitch;
cudaStatus = cudaMallocPitch(&d_M, &pitch, sizeof(float)*(N), M+1);
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc Failed!");
    INFO;
    return CUDA_MALLOC_ERROR;
}
```

This variable represents a matrix with dimension NxM+1. After doing some elaboration on the GPU with an ad-hoc cuda function, I would to sum the elements of each row using the thrust library and put the result on the M+1 column of each row.

For such operation I would use the thrust library. 
My intention should be to retrieve the **raw pointer** created using the cudaMallocPitch, convert it to a **thrust::device_ptr** and then operate on it using the thrust function. So, in code:

```
    thrust::device_ptr<float> dd_M = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_M);
```

But, when I try to print the addresses of both variables to make sure that the pointer have the same address:

```
printf("Address d_M: %p\n", &d_M);
printf("Address dd_M: %p\n", &dd_M);
```

I get different values for the addresses. I don't what I'm doing wrong. For such operation I've just followed the thrust manual at the link [Thrust - Memory Management Functions](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__memory__management__functions.html#gab16468f547bc65cdcb3d240d0c023110).

Comment: I don't believe there is an easy way of doing this

Comment: You won't be able to use thrust conveniently with `cudaMallocPitch`.  Use `cudaMalloc` instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with cudaMalloc. Thanks

Comment: Agreed that there is not a convenient way to use `cudaMallocPitch` here. However, the reason the outputs of your `printfs` don't match is because you're printing the address of two different variables -- not the raw pointers you're actually interested in. You want to print the values of the raw pointers `d_m` and `dd_M.get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cudaMallocPitch` is going to be essentially unusable with thrust.  This is because it creates an allocation like this:

```
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X
...
```

where the `D` items represent your actual data and the `X` items represent extra space appended to each row to make your data width match the desired machine pitch.

The problem is that thrust has no concept of this "unused" region represented by `X`.  There is no *convenient* way to tell a thrust function to assign threads (and generate appropriate, contiguous indexing) when the data has the "unused" gaps in it.  So if we convert the above to a thrust vector:

```
D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X D D D D D D D D D D D D D D X X D D ...
```

the `X` regions scattered through the vector cannot be conveniently "skipped" in thrust algorithms and indexing.  If you really wanted to do this, it might be possible to come up with a `thrust::permutation_iterator` that resolved the above mapping, but that is going to have its own inefficiencies associated with it that would outweigh any performance benefits from operating on pitched data.

If you use `cudaMalloc` instead, then your data will be contiguous, the way thrust expects.

Comment: I was thinking that a custom container class with pointer semantics might be the "easiest" way to do this. A permutation iterator probably would not work because there is no guarantee (or requirement) that allocation pitches are round multiples of the array type size

Comment: I agree with your point about permutation iterator not being kosher - at least for non-POD types that don't evenly divide into the pitch (and even relying on that for POD types is not kosher).  So, I don't really know how to do it in the general case.